# UIAlertController gone crazy, point to settings when it should cancel

Tags: xcode, swift, uialertcontroller

Anyone ever had an alert controller with a "cancel" action and just a return in the handler that does something?

Mine goes to the app settings....

I have another alert controller in another viewcontroller that does that. But that shouldn't affect this one????

```
alertControl.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
            return
        }))
```

update:

Commented all other alertController out. (They were all in other view controller) now it doesn't do it anymore. What is this??

These are also only declared in a function when something goes wrong. When there is no connection,... They shouldn't even exist, unless the function gets called.

update 2 :

```
func checkAllSettingsForLocation() {
        if isTest != true {
        //println("should show this")

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Scenix can't use your location", message: "Check Location Services under Privacy in the Settings App", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let goToSettingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .Default, handler: {
            action in
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
            return

            }
        )
        alertController.addAction(goToSettingsAction)

        let ignoreNoCamAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: {
            action in
            self.launch = self.launch - 1
            return

            }
        )
        alertController.addAction(ignoreNoCamAction)

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Update 3:

Looks more and more like an Xcode Bug.

Building for release / through test flight and the bug is there.
Do a normal debug build and all is fine....

---

dirty fix =>

Wrap the action from any alert controller in an if statement that checks the alert controller title. Can never throw an exception or result in finding a nil and fixed my problem.

Comment: Can you show more context? How and where are these two "conflicting" alert controllers declared? Thanks.

Comment: i declare all my alert controllers in functions. They don't need to exist unless something goes wrong. The one that is doing things it isn't supposed to lives in the third viewcontroller. The others in the first. (when navigating)

Comment: p.s. the alertcontroller/alerts/handlers all have different names.

Comment: Could this be the compiler?

Comment: Changing the build settings does fix it aswel. Really makes me think it is an Xcode bug. It happens when I build for release (I do this since I had other bugs that only happened with through test flight downloaded versions) I'll put it on test flight and see what happens.

Comment: "Building for release and the bug is there. Do a normal debug build and all is fine" Okay, that is really suggestive, isn't it? That sort of difference sounds like a bug - as if some important distinction were being optimized away. I really wish I could reproduce it. If you have time, maybe you could reduce it to a simple case and package it up and put it on github? Or just use the simple case to file a bug report with Apple. Sorry you got hit with this, but you're being a noble pioneer, exploring the jungle for the rest of us...

Comment: So I tested with flight test to be sure (it might also have been my personal build settings) But no bug is definitely there. I also changed everything that said cancel from the cancel alert to something else (apple also uses the word cancel), still no fix. I think something goes wrong when an alert has a handler but nothing in it. So setting it to nil works and checking for the title of the alertcontroller also works. I am still pretty new at this. So my first thought is always that I screwed up.

Comment: I'm glad you are humble enough to blame yourself first and the compiler second; this is a good attitude and I wish more people had it. Nevertheless, I'm here to tell you that there are a number of subtle optimization bugs connected with doing a Release build in Swift. If this is one, and if you can boil it down to a clear test case, submit it as a bug report to Apple! They definitely want to know about it.

Comment: I found the bug on a very last round of test before release off the app. An alert controller that got altered a couple of days ago. (2 instead of 3 options) I never tested the cancel options because I was always testing the "do something" options. So after some rest I will try to get to the bottom of this and see if I can create something simple with the bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using nil instead of return,

`let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
alertController.addAction(cancel)`

I also have some other setting destination alert controllers, and this has worked fine for me.

Comment: Yes, I was going to comment on the odd way the OP was doing this, but it never occurred to me that this could be what had exposed the problem he was seeing! NIce one.

Comment: Ya it was definitely a shot in the dark.